# Google add-on: how to avoid per user authorization when admin installed

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, add-on

[image]
Attached is an image of what I'm worried about. We would like to develop Google Add-on which will be admin installed, but we want it to be seamless for the end-users in the organization. I encountered this authorization message in Gmail when admin installing.
How can I avoid this and deploy the add-on seamlessly to all users?
Meaning they won't have to take this extra step of authorization.

Also- we currently have this app: https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/wisestamp_email_signature_management_for/842844122024

It's not an add-on, and it doesn't require per-user authorization. Why?
What's the difference between app and add-on?
Can we simply edit the existing app to add add-on functionality?
What's the definition of our existing app? add-on?

Thank you!

Admin install google add-on, I expected to not have end-user authorization.
What actually happened is that even when I installed it centrally, all add-ons requires end-user authorization.